# UK Standard Visitor visa rejection under Appendix V, paragraph 4.2(a)

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, serial-refusals

I have provided  all the documents, which is usually sought by the UK embassy. This is the third rejection  letter which I received today. Before going to discuss my case, I would like to tell you  something about my background. I am not from very rich class.  I belong to middle class section of India. Working as an assistant professor in India. My annual package is approx 4915 pounds as per the Indian economy. I took the semester break N.O.C from University whenever I supposed to going out of country, which I also appended  along with visa applications  . My visa category is a tourist visa for the six months. I have shown them 2600 pounds as the current balance. The last time I have  shown them 5000 pounds, but they have straightly rejected on the basis of intuitive feeling that how could a person spend his 6 months salary on any tour. Moreover, they were doubted about fluctuation in my bank balance. My invitee is a native British citizen. She has invited me visiting her country, Britain.

I am genuinely seeking tourist visa, so where am I lagging in the whole scenario? I shall be grateful to you if you please suggest me how much money should I really show them, so that I do not waste my money for zero output?

Here are the documents I attached :

1. My six months bank balance
2. My six months salary proof
3. My appointment letter which stated that I have been working as A.P for the last year.
4. N.O.C (Non-objection certificate) from University
5. Dummy tickets
6. Invitee deeds (Land registry)
7. Invitee  sponsor letter
8. Invitee bank balance
9. Reason of returning to my native country
10. Cover letter
11. The last two refusal letters
12. All the photocopies of visa, Which I got so far.
13. Invitee visa copies ( when invitee came to India).
    Letter docx.
    "REFUSAL OF A VISIT VISA
    Post reference:
    /

To:

Date of Birth:

Nationality:
INDIA
Your application for a visit visa to the United Kingdom has been refused.
How your application was considered
You have applied for a visa to visit the UK
In deciding whether you meet the requirements of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for visitors
(https://www.gov,u
ovemmenticollectionsiimmigration-rules)
, I have considered:
•
your application, and any additional relevant information you have provided with it
•
your immigration history
The decision
I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the
requirements of paragraph(s) 4.2 of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitors because:
•
The Immigration Rules require me to be satisfied about your intentions, as well as those of
your sponsor. I must take into consideration your own personal circumstances and it is your
responsibility to ensure you submit sufficient evidence. Your economic circumstances are
also relevant to your application, especially in the absence of any previous travel history to
the UK or any other country.
•
When
an
application
is
refused
the
applicant
is
invited
to
reapply
if
their
personal
circumstances change
significantly between
now and the next application;
or they provide
compelling
new
evidence
with
the
next
application.
I
have
considered
the
evidence
contained
in your application,
however I am satisfied that your personal circumstance have
not changed,
and
although you
have submitted extra documents,
I do
not consider that it
provides any further compelling evidence in support of your application.
•
I must consider your personal circumstances when I assess your application for a visit visa
and from the document you have provided, you have not established that your
circumstances are as claimed.
This leads me to doubt your intentions and I am therefore"

---

(Gayot's edit, moving scan of the refusal notice to this site)

[image: http://imgur.com/a/NTKHS]

[image]

Comment: @AlokDhaundiyal Please upload the entire **first** refusal letter

Comment: ok, now fixed and moving forward. I can see what's going on here. They got you on 4.2 (a) and cited (a)+(c)+(e) secondarily. You are not going to get a visa from them for a while. You need to stop applying!  Site members will start composing their answers, it will take some time. Please be patient.  Adding, yeah I will get to your never leaving India in my answer, as will others hopefully :)

Comment: I shall be obliged if you please suggest me some valuable tips.

Comment: @Crazydre +1 on your comment, that's a good idea and will even IMPROVE the quality of more answers! Tell the OP again!

Comment: @AlokDhaundiyal Like I said, please upload all pages of the **first and second** visa refusals you got

Comment: @AlokDhaundiyal honestly, getting your complete history will dramatically improve the quality.

Comment: @Crazydre you can go ahead and write it up and then upgrade if the OP includes more stuff

Answer (score 9):

You are a lower-tiered academic who proposes to visit the UK during a semester break. Your financial position is weak and you are using a UK-based co-sponsor. You have applied three times unsuccessfully.  A previous refusal was for disproportionate outlay (that's a bad thing). The exhibits in your question are from your 3rd refusal and it is a natural and predictable follow-on to the previous refusal.

> I shall be obliged if you please suggest me some valuable tips.

You are in a tailspin of serial refusals and the ECO has made it clear that this chain of events has taken a life of its own ("*...I am satisfied that your personal circumstances have not changed...*"). The immediate remedy for serial refusals is to **stop applying**. While this "tip" may seem unnecessarily  pedantic, we have serial refusal cases in the archives here that demonstrate people routinely ignore it.  From the ECO's viewpoint you are obsessed with getting in to the UK and that's a very wrong message to send them. So stop applying, forget it, go elsewhere for a holiday, or rendez-vous with your sponsor in a 3rd country, or get diplomatic credentials, or become a monk on a mountain top and get them to come to you, or whatever; it's not going to work for you until your circumstances have been changed at the roots and branches.

> I didn't get what immigration history, they were talking about ?

They were referring to your two, now three refusals. It's your history. It is bound to you like Acrocorinthus is bound to Sisyphus. Like Robin and his merry men... Like Chip and Dale, you and your history will be together and they will look with increasing scepticism at every application you make (which gets further  appended to your history). That message virtually jumps off the page and they have been really clear about it. And for your implicit question...

> So what to do about it?

You (implicitly) want to know how to break the chain of serial refusals and to clear the record and to enjoy some mobility.  Fortunately there is a wonderful panacea for this: successfully apply for an entry clearance. Once you have done this, your history will fade into irrelevance. There is no other cure quite like it. You show them an entry clearance and BAM future applications will go straight to the green triage on the first sift. Some might go to the orange triage, but this is where people have become overconfident.

This cure-all has a paradox that some see as cruel, how to break the chain when a refusal is all but certain?  There are two ways:

1. Change your personal circumstances in a visible and radical way. For
   you it means advance in your career, get some promising standing in your 
   career, show some commitment and dedication to your career for a
   while, organise a family, maintain an independent lifestyle whilst
   achieving financial solvency, and all the rest of those things.  OR
2. Instruct a solicitor with a nationally acknowledged practice area in
   serial refusals. You can expect this to be **bloody expensive**, but the
   option is there for you. We're talking in the neighbourhood of GBP 3,800 or so to unsnarl your imbroglio (if they even take you on) but that's a pure guess on my part.

In all events, stop applying.

Comment: the more refusal you got, the lesser is the chance of getting visa ?  or they  consider  the fresh application with  different  perspective?

Comment: Acutually, my co-sponsor is obsessed. I was not willing to apply after getting the second  refusal.

Comment: @AlokDhaundiyal they only consider the fresh application from a different perspective if your personal circumstances have changed significantly. That just can not happen in a short period of time.